# Infinitely nested radical indexed by powers of two

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations, nested-radicals

This nested radical is one that I keep unsuccessfully working on solving. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371769/infinitely-nested-radical-problem)
$$G(0)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{8+\cdots}}}}$$
In recurrence form, this can be written as 
$$G(x)^2=2^{x-1}+G(x+1)$$
and then evaluated at $x=1$

Ramanujan showed that for some nested radical of the form
$$F(x)^2=ax+(a+n)^2+xF(x+n)$$
then
$$F(x)=a+x+n$$

To get $G(x)$ into that form, we can say 
$$G(x)^2=\frac{2^{x-1}}{j(x-1)}+xG(x+1)$$
where $$j(x)=\prod_{i=1}^x (x-i+1)^{({2^i})}$$
which can be defined as
$$j(x)=(xj(x-1))^2$$
with
$$j(0)=1$$
Setting $n=1$, I thought that $F(x)=G(x)$ when $$ax+(a+1)^2=\frac{2^{x-1}}{j(x-1)}$$
Naturally I want to set $x=1$ because I want to find $G(1)$, but then we'll have $a=0$.  Putting everything together we'd get $F(1)=0+1+1\ne{G(1)}$.

Trying different values of $x$ and $a$ and then correcting for the required iterations doesn't work either.  What's wrong?

Comment: Is is trivial that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{8+\sqrt{16+\ldots}}}}}$ converges to a finite value? It is not to me, at least.

Comment: That is trivial I think.  The finite value is what I want to find. Why is it not trivial to you?

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1274352/269624

Comment: @TyO'Brien: well, if it is trivial: why $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{4+\ldots}}}$ converges to a finite value?

Comment: As I've already hinted at about a year and a half ago, in the comment section of the post linked to in the very body of the question itself, even [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A257576) has no earthly idea about a possible closed form for this infinitely nested expression.